# effects of using underscorejs templates on SEO

Tags: templates, seo, underscore.js

I have a website where I am using underscorejs.
I have many templates(underscorejs) included in the HTML.

there are cases where unnecessary templates are being read on the pages.
Does this effect the SEO rating of my site.

I have heard that Google Search engine reduces the ranking of your site if it finds no Javascript code within `<script>` tags.

and while specifying underscorejs templates we specify it

```
<script type="text/template" id="XXX"></script>
```

PS: I understand that readig unnecessary templates is not good , but this is done from a long time in the site and I dont intend to edit it anytime soon.

Answer (score 5):

The problem I see here is that, since you are using templates that are loaded via Javascript (e.g. Underscore or Handlebars), some search engines will have problems to index your website (although there are techniques to improve indexation).

I imagine that you are building a single-page web application which is rendered in the client side via Javascript using Underscore templates; and I guess you are making AJAX calls to the server to do CRUD operations if needed.

The problem with the SEO in single-page applications is well known. [Here](http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/) is an interesting article (specially interesting if you are using BackboneJs).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549306/single-page-js-websites-and-seo) is a thread in Stackoverflow dealing with Single-page web applications and SEO.

[One more resource](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/): "Making AJAX applications crawlable" from Google.

I hope this helps.