# backbone vs turbolinks for search engine with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, turbolinks

I'm working on a small search engine with tire and elastic search. I just started the project and I would like the search to be as fast as possible.

What technology should I use for this purpose, turbolinks or backbone.js?

Also. I would like to know how I can solve the problem of "Seo" with these technologies.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Backbone with ajax requests will be slightly faster than using Turbolinks.

However, Turbolinks will provides SEO by default, whereas you have to do a lot of work to make Backbone and SEO work ([See this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549306/single-page-js-websites-and-seo))

You'll also have to write a lot of JavaScript if you use Backbone compared to writing hardly any JavaScript if you use Turbolinks.

It's really up to you to weigh the pros and cons and decide which option is better for your situation though.