# Indexe site in angular by search robots if $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) (without !#)

Tags: html, angularjs, seo, search-engine-bots

friends.

I have site written in angular.
How google or other search robots indexing this sites?
What techniques can be used to allow robots to see pages content?

Internet says how optimise site on angular for indexing if $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
Exist method for indexing site if url of pages like: http://example.com/!#audio/1234

But in my site $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
That means that url of pages without !#
http://example.com/audio/1234.
But all content of page loades with javascript.

I need help.

Comment: Hello, if You want the url like this http://site.com/!#audio/1234 $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); does not make the difference.
To do this use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server will receive a request at `http://site.com/audio/1234`. Somehow you will need to be able to return some content.

For now the only strategy I know is to render that page on the server-side also... Which involved some (or a lot of) work.

It's also good for the browsers that does not support pushStates yet. That way these users can still access the data.

You can also take a look at this http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable They render the page on the server-side by executing the client-side javascript on the server-side.

Here's a similar question: [pushState and SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193858/pushstate-and-seo)